# Change Javascript font using css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i just started using js and i try adding date to my web, i used this code:

**extrnal script_**

```
var mydate=new Date() 
var year=mydate.getYear() 
if (year < 1000) year+=1900 
var day=mydate.getDay() 
var month=mydate.getMonth() 
var daym=mydate.getDate() 
if (daym"+dayarray[day]+", "+montharray[month]+" "+daym+", "+year+ "")
```

the problem is inside my html file it look like this :

```
 <p><strong>Current Date is : </strong><script src="js/datescript.js" id="sc"></script><br>
```

i want the text of the script to match the text of the `<p>`, how can i do this?

Comment: please specify your problem clearly.

Comment: Assuming that's the entire script (it looks like there's a big chunk missing), it should match already. Can you show us what's happening, using http://jsfiddle.net/ or something similar?

Comment: I don't understand the placement of the script.... `<script>...</script>` isn't evaluated or reduced to text and filled into that spot in the page, like inline PHP or a templating language might do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is the following:

STEP 1:

Make an HTML element with a unique ID to the variable part of the date. For instance:

```
<p><strong>Current Date is : <span id="dateVar"></span></strong>
```

STEP 2:

Make your external JavaScript execute a function when the document is ready (preferred use of jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    showDate();
}

function showDate() {
    var mydate=new Date();
    var year=mydate.getYear();
    if (year < 1000) {
        year+=1900;
    } 
    var day=mydate.getDay();
    var month=mydate.getMonth();
    var daym=mydate.getDate();

    //Get dateString
    var element = document.getElementById('dateVar'); // Get the HTML element which should contain your variable
    element.innerHtml = *yourDateString*;
}
```

That's about all you have to do to show your date inside an HTML on page load. If you want it to show on a button click, you can call the function showDate() again after setting an on-click event-listener (more info on that can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, some of your Javascript seems to be missing and the last **if** statement is *way* off, there is no `dayarray`, or `montharray` specified.

Secondly, the JS is simply assigning variables not outputting anything, and when you include the script inline- it will not 'inject' output into that part of the DOM.

Likely the best thing to do is assign the element you wish the output to appear in an `id` then output the desired content into it.

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mh5Pp/1/)

HTML

```
 <p id='date'><strong>Current Date is : </strong></p>
```

Javascript

```
var mydate = new Date();
var year = mydate.getYear();
if (year < 1000) year += 1900;

var day = mydate.getDay();
var month = mydate.getMonth();
var daym = mydate.getDate();

var el= document.getElementById('date');                            el.innerHTML+=mydate;
```

**Update**

If you wish for the output to also be bold, simply move the `id` and change your HTML per:

HTML

```
 <p><strong id='date'>Current Date is : </strong></p>
```

Comment: This seems to be an effort to correct the errors in the code in the question but doesn't actually address the question.

Comment: @Quentin - I read `i want the text of the script to match the text of the <p>, how can i do this?` to infer a desire to have a) the script output something within the `p`, and b) the output to be formatted as text in the `p` is.

Comment: Look at your JSFiddle. The text in the HTML is styled differently from the text generated by the JS.

Comment: @Quentin look at the OP question- the output JS falls outside the `strong` tags so should not be bold. I've used some creative freedom for the resultant output due to the missing variables in the JS

Comment: The output JS falling outside the string tags is, presumably, the cause of problem and moving it inside is the solution.

Comment: Good call..I've added it as an example, seems like the Q is up to a fair bit of interpretation!

Comment: @user3436708 no problem, so what was the answer in the end?

Comment: el.innerHTML+=mydate.
like i said this was my fairst js used, so i still dont know all the keywords. hope to learn and improve..

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript just outputs HTML (well, the JS you've included in the question doesn't, but I'm assuming your real script does actually generate some content). You style that HTML the same way as any other HTML.

Since the script element is inside the paragraph, the generated text nodes will be styled the same was as the other text nodes that are child nodes of the paragraph.

The problem is that you don't have any child nodes like that. The rest of the text in the paragraph is inside a `<strong>` element.

Move the script inside the `<strong>` element if you want the text it generates to be styled the same way as the rest of the text.

Answer (score -1):

There are several errors in you external JS, which need to be fixed first:

```
var mydate=new Date(); // terminate statements with ; always!
var year=mydate.getYear();
if (year < 1000) 
    year+=1900;
var day=mydate.getDay();
var month=mydate.getMonth();
var daym=mydate.getDate();

if (daym"+dayarray[day]+", "+montharray[month]+" "+daym+", "+year+ "") 
  // dayarray and montharray are undefined
  // the if has no statement or block: if ( expression ) statement;
```